# Generic return Method to be defined by generic parameter in method

Tags: java, generics, return-type

I have an interface in Java:

```
public interface IElement{

    public String getId();
    public String getName();

    /***
     * adds an IElement to this elements children
     * @param child
     */
    void getAddChild(IElement child);

    /***
     * returns all children
     * @return
     */
    Collection<IElement> getChildren( );

    /***
     * returns all children which match the Class of the passed IElement
     * @param eType - the class type to match
     */ 
    Collection<IElement> getChildren( Class<? extends IElement> eType);
}
```

The idea is that an `IElement` may contain a collection of other `IElement`s.

I need the method `Collection<IElement> getChildren(Class<? extends IElement> eType)` to return a collection of matching siblings.

Say I had a three classes which all extend `IElement`.
One was called `Room`, 
another was called `Box` (`box1`, `box2`, `box3`),
and another was called `Shelve` (`shelve1`)

Now with an instance of a `Room` I can do the following:

```
room1.addChildren(box1);
room1.addChildren(box2);
room1.addChildren(shelve1,sheleve2);
room1.addChildren(box3);
```

Now I have a `Room` (`room1`) with three different boxes in it and a `Shelve` (`shelve1`). 
Now I would like to get all `Box` objects inside `room1` using the `Collection<IElement> getChildren(Class<? extends IElement> eType);` method,
as in `room1.getChildren(Box.class)`. However, the method only returns a collection of `IElement`s. I would like it to return `Collection<Box>`.
If I passed `Shelve` then it should return a collection of `Shelve` objects.

Is this possible? And if so, how do you do it? 
I know this seems odd, but I have a lot of different objects which can all hold other Elements, and I need a quick and easy way to filter for different types.

Comment: Your `getChildren` method should have a named generic type; e.g. `<E extends IElement> Collection<E> getChildren(Class<E> eType)` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a generic method with a named generic type, instead of using a wildcard.

```
<E extends IElement> Collection<E> getChildren(Class<E> eType);
```

That way, the generic type of the collection you get out will match the class that you passed in.

Your implementation will have to construct and return a collection of the appropriate generic type for its argument.

Comment: it works a treat! although I am not quiet sure what it does, but I will look that up.

Comment: Oh sorry. Thanks a million!